# how to move div in css

Tags: html, css, position, margin

how to move the text position to up sign 
when i change margin top of the div text sign div it moves the sidenav with it

```
.sign {
    color: #C9B5AD;
    margin-top: -190px;
    z-index: 3;
    text-align: center;
}
.sidenav {
    background-color: #CEBAB2;
    margin-top: -612px;
    clear: both;
    width: 12%;
    height: 722px;
    float: right;
}
```

[image]

Comment: *how to move the text position to up zeftsign* Which text and what is `zeftsign` exactly ? Also create a snippet with the relevant code illustrating the issue, otherwise it'll be a guessing game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use transform property

```
   transform: translateY(-612px)
```